# How to do gsutil cp -R while ignoring files like .git, .gitignore?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gsutil

I am trying to automate the process of syncing my web assets with Google Cloud Storage. I basically need to copy everything in my development directory up to the cloud. However, I need to ignore the `.git` directory and some other irrelevant files.

I can't just do a `gsutil cp -R . <dest>` because that takes absolutely everything, including `.git`.
I tried `find . | fgrep git | gsutil cp -I <dest>` but that flattens all directories and puts them in root!

Is there a way I can solve this with `gsutil` or do I have to do a loop in script which uploads all directories (except `.git`) with `-R` and then uploads individual files in current directory?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [rsync will not exclude hidden files in gsutil 4.15](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33702631/rsync-will-not-exclude-hidden-files-in-gsutil-4-15)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have two options:

A) Remove the git files after they are uploaded:

```
gsutil rm gs://bucket/\*.git\*
```

B) Use find to exclude git files:

```
find . -not -path '*/.git' -type f -printf '%P\n' | xargs -I '{}' gsutil cp '{}' gs://bucket/'{}'
```

Source: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gsutil-discuss/zoHhkTPhiNc

It would've been much easier if gsutil implemented rsync, this would've been easier with their --exclude flag.

Answer (score 42):

You could use a command like:

```
gsutil rsync -x '\.git.*' dev_dir gs://your-bucket
```

See Google Storage - [rsync - Synchronize content of two buckets/directories](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/rsync)

Comment: This is an appropriate answer. Not sure why it got downvoted.

Comment: This has the downside of not being able to use `-z js,css,json,html,svg` to put these files in GCS compressed with gzip. This makes the storage cost slightly smaller, but the key value of it is that **without this the files will be served from the GCS bucket without compression**.

Answer (score 0):

Your web assets are text files - JS, CSS, etc. - which you want to serve compressed, don't you?

Then you need to be aware that GCS requires you to *upload* such files compressed, to *serve* them compressed!

Therefore you want to use the `-z` parameter of `gsutil` to compress such files.

Expanding on Aziz Saleh's answer then, you probably want to do this:

`path '*/.git' -type f -printf '%P\n' | xargs -I '{}' gsutil cp -z js,css,json,html,htm,xml '{}' gs://bucket/'{}'`

(You cannot use `-z` parameter with the Mike Schwartz's `gsutil rsync` solution.)

Read more about `gsutil cp` [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp) and about "Transcoding of gzip-compressed files" [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/transcoding).