# rsync will not exclude hidden files in gsutil 4.15

Tags: google-cloud-storage

Previously gsutil appeared to not upload hidden files.  Now hidden files cannot be prevented from upload.  Using the -x command with either
`.*/\\..*`  or
`.*/[.].*`  still uploads both hidden files and directories.
This is with a local directory up to a bucket.

Is there a different expression that is required?

Comment: If you think one of the posts answers your question, feel free to mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-x` exclude option should work:

```
gsutil rsync -x '\..*|./[.].*$' source-dir gs://your-bucket
```

You can learn more about it from the [official documentation].

Comment: That correctly handled the top level hidden folders.  The final solution is '\..*|./[.].*$'

Comment: `\..*|./[.].*$` is not working for me with `.DS_Store` files.

Comment: Doesn't work for me with `env/.Python`

Comment: Oh, had to escape `/`

Answer (score 1):

This works for both hidden files and directories, at any spot in the path:

```sh
gsutil rsync -x '.*/\..*|^\..*' source dest
```

The other answer didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

As the regexp is not tied to the edges of the string, `.*`'s at the beginning and at the end are not necessary, plus we can use grouping to simplify (sic!) a bit:

```
gsutil rsync -x '(^|/)\.' source dest
```

Where `\.` is the dot itself and `(^|/)` states that the dot should follow either the beginning of file name (`^`) or a `/` - a dot file in a subfolder.